# How to test $on event defined in directive link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Using angular 1.4.8 and Karma 0.13.19, I'd like to trigger a $on callback defined in a link to then test that it well sets scope properties according to the data that callback gets.

Here is my directive

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('error').directive('errorPopup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'components/error/error_popup-template.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('_REQUEST_ERROR_', function (event, response) {
                scope.error = response;
                console.log('on _REQUEST_ERROR_; scope.error: ', scope.error);
                element.modal();
            });
        }
    };
  });
})();
```

here is my test

```
describe('Error-Popup Directive', function(){
  var $templateCache,
    scope,
    element,
    elementScope,
    $compile,
    listener = {},
    response;

  beforeEach(module('error'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($templateCache, $compile, $rootScope) {
    response = {
        'data': {
            'code': 'INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN',
            'message': 'Authentication token is missing'
        }
    };
    $templateCache.put('components/error/error_popup-template.html', '<div>some html</div>');
    element = angular.element('<error-popup></error-popup>');

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    // elementScope = element.scope;
    spyOn(scope, '$on').and.callFake(function(event, callback) {
        // Store event listeners for later access.
        console.log('event:', event);
        listener[event] = callback;
        console.log('listener['+event+']:', listener[event]);
    });

    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  describe('scope.$on(\'_REQUEST_ERROR_\', callback )', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        listener['_REQUEST_ERROR_']({},  response);
        console.log('scope:', scope);
    });

    it('should set scope.error to response', function() {
        expect(scope.error).toEqual(response);
    });
  });
});
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'listener['_REQUEST_ERROR_']({},  response)'`

It looks like link function is never called so is scope.$on.

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The spyon doesn't work because the link function is executed before jasmine spyon.

if you really want to test it, you can broadcast the event in your test and check the event handler result.

Comment: I'm able to broadcast an event but turns out scope.error stays undefined when testing it, even after it passes through listener callback and scope.error has been set properly (console.log attests it)

Comment: did you do scope.$apply()?

Comment: No when should I do  `scope.$apply()` ?

Comment: after you broadcast the event.